# Any ssh options or ssh client that is tolerant to network failure?

Tags: ssh, vpn, connection

Here is my scenario

I run a VPN client to initiate connection to my corporate network.  The VPN will disconnect every 24 hrs.  I can reconnect immediately.  I initiate ssh sessions to some servers after establishing VPN connection.

The problem I have is I lose the ssh session every 24 hrs.  I do have screens running to regain my sessions.

Is there an ssh client or ssh option that will tolerate 30 seconds or 1 min of break in the link with the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `autossh`. Links to [home page](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/), [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh). If you are using Linux then it's probably packaged in your distribution.